# I need to make some(logical multiplication) program but I cannot fix one of error

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Let's do some logical multiplication, shall we?(In binary notation (press 'Enter' to continue))");
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                Environment.Exit(38250968);
            Console.WriteLine("Let's enter some arguments for it?(press 'Enter' to continue)");
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                Environment.Exit(38250968);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of argument Q and then press 'Enter'");
            int q = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
            string w = Convert.ToString(q, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of argument E and then press 'Enter'");
            int e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string r = Convert.ToString(e, 10); ;
            string t = Convert.ToString($"{w&r}"); //error is on this line
            Console.WriteLine("Making some magic. Please wait");
            await Task.Delay(1024);
#pragma warning disable CA2241 // Provide correct arguments to formatting methods
            Console.WriteLine("The magic worked, and we got a response of");
            double i = Convert.ToDouble(t);
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
#pragma warning restore CA2241 // Provide correct arguments to formatting methods
            await Task.Delay(1024);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(3948);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it? Shows "CS0019: Operator '&' cannot be applied to the operand of type 'string' and 'string'". I don't found a really valuable solution, so I ask you for help

Comment: Whats the expected output on this line? & is a binary operator and as error says it cant be applied to strings

Comment: What are you expecting `w&r` to *do*? Also, unless you're using an odd version of C#, you're allowed to use multiple characters in naming your variables - try giving them more meaningful names.

Comment: To make *some program* you don't really need that line and any other line, just delete them all. If you think it's needed, then maybe explaining what *logical multiplication* is will be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use + operator instead of &.

Comment: ```
int x1 = 2; //010(binary view)
int y1 = 5;//101(binary view)
Console.WriteLine(x1&y1); // print 0
```
I need to make logical multiplication( don't know, how to translate it into English)

Answer (score 0):

While the ***&*** operator in VB.net will concatenate strings, in C# it has a total other meaning, namely a boolean or bitwise logical AND. But that's definitely not what you need here.

To correct your error, change the line on which the error occurs with this:

```
string t = Convert.ToString($"{w + r}"); //error is no longer on this line
```

or, even simpeler, since no conversion is needed, as w and r are already strings, and the concatenation result as well:

```
 string t = w + r;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intend was to do a logical AND operation, you should do this with the integer numbers q and e that you already converted.

If you need the result as string you could convert it after the logical operation

```
string t = Convert.ToString(q & e);
```

Comment: The error did not go away((

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: cs0019. But I found one solution. I will try to use it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that for string, however you can try this

```
   int t = q & e;
   decimal output = Convert.ToDecimal(t);
```